# Не могу конвертировать в pdf

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Когда в jupyter notebook выбираю Save and export notebook as pdf выдает ошибку:

nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:

Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:

miktex-dvipdfmx: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, главная проблема: "So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates." означает, что у Вас старая версия miktext.